# Speed up junit tests in ant build

Tags: java, ant, junit

I was watching our ant build run the other day and noticed that most of our junit tests run < 0.2 seconds but it takes ant 1-2 seconds to cycle between them. This is probably the single greatest block of time in our typical build.

So I was wondering if I created a test suite, would that help remove the overhead time for each test and just spend the overhead one time for a whole block of tests? Also, does anyone else have a better idea?

Comment: What fork settings do you use when running the tests?

Comment: Can you try this please and post the results? http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/performance_monitor.html

Comment: @richcoleuk I downloaded the source for the current version, 1.05b, since I couldn't find an excecutable, and figured out how to build it. Then I added to the classpath and it told me the listener wasn't found. I looked into the jar I build and there was no net.sf.antcontrib.perf.AntPerformanceListener in fact no net.sf.antcontrib.perf at all. Now what?

Comment: Why do you need to download the source?  How are you invoking ant with it on the cp?  Have you added the jar to the ant_home/lib directory?

Comment: @richcoleuk As I said, there was no binary for 1.05 that I could find. I did add the jar to the build, but it did no good because the jar did not include the AntPerformanceListener, like I said above.

Comment: can you be specific by what you mean "add the jar to the build"

Comment: @richcoleuk I could, but what's the point? Are you missing the fact that I'm telling you that I opened the jar and it doesn't contain AntPerformanceListener?

Comment: No idea what you've downloaded but it's definately in this download http://sourceforge.net/projects/ant-contrib/files/ant-contrib/1.0b3/ant-contrib-1.0b3-bin.zip/download

Comment: @richcoleuk Well that certainly worked better, but after I ran it with the listener I got no report back. the build said "Build Successful" at the end and then just sat there in my eclipse environment until I hit the stop button. How is this supposed to help me, anyway? I already know what takes the longest in my build.

Comment: I think the `fork="true"` is killing the performance, because that creates a new JVM for every single test. Adding `forkmode="once"` might mitigate that effect, assuming that your test can be run all together in one JVM and do not need that complete isolation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had placed `fork="yes"` on our junit tests to solve some problem we were having ages ago. I can't remember what it was, but I just tried switching it to `forkmode="once"` on Clemens advice and it cut three minutes from our build time.

Thanks for all the help.